# Any extra field present in request body in laravel API

Tags: api, laravel-8, laravel-validation

Suppose my API required following json in request

```
{
   "name":"User Name",
   "email":"user@email.com"
 }
```

But user sending following json in request:

```
{
   "name":"User Name",
   "email":"user@email.com",
   "phone":"1234467"
 }
```

At controller side every thing works fine, validation performed on "name" & "email" and whole request is executed successfully. Where as the "phone" field is ignored silently without raising any flag.

The user never know that he/she had passed any extra field in request, which are not needed in request.

Is there any way to validated such scenario, like present of unknown field in request, like "phone"?

Answer (score 0):

except() method could retrieve any other field present as array, and that is countable.

```
$excepts =$request->except(['email','name']);
if(count($excepts))
  // do your stuff
```